# What's caffe's input format?

Tags: c++, caffe, leveldb

I'm try to use `caffe` for audio recognition, but can't find a document for its input format.

I want to use `leveldb`, thus I must create a key and a value for each record, which is a pair of label string and data byte array.

It seems that no document describes this, and after I found the value is written by `Datum.SerializeToString()`, I can't find where `Datum` is and then lost.

Does anyone know how to convert non-image records into `leveldb` records for `caffe`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datum object is defined with protobuf. See here:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L30-L41

It generates a file `caffe.pb.h` in `.build_release/src/caffe/proto` with the class `Datum`. You can have a look there to understand how this object works.

Comment: I found protobuf's official document: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding
I was confused with "proto" since I thought it was "prototype" in caffe :/

Answer (score 3):

`leveldb`, `lmdb` and `HDF5` are currently the main formats for feeding data into Caffe. The `MemoryData` layer enable in-memory input as well, so it's possible to use whatever input format and and use Caffe's python or c++ interfaces to populate the data blobs.

If you're already set on `leveldb`, [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/745) discussion on caffe issues could be useful.

Below is an example for populating a `leveldb` with python. It requires pycaffe and plyvel. It's adapted from [caffe's github issues](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/745) posted by [Zackory](https://github.com/Zackory). It's not specific to images as long as you represent each example in the form of a CxHxW where any or all can be equal to 1:

```
import caffe

db = plyvel.DB('train_leveldb/', create_if_missing=True, error_if_exists=True, write_buffer_size=268435456)
wb = db.write_batch()
count = 0
for file in dataset:
    mat = # load numpy array from file

    # Load matrix into datum object
    datum = caffe.io.array_to_datum(mat)

    wb.put('%08d_%s' % (count, file), datum.SerializeToString())

    count += 1

    # Write to db in regular intervals
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        # Write batch of images to database
        wb.write()
        del wb
        wb = db.write_batch()

    # Write last batch of images
    if count % 1000 != 0:
        wb.write()
```

I find constructing lmdb a lot simpler. `lmdb` example [here](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/).